# Transposing / pivoting rows to columns in Cascalog?

Tags: clojure, cascading, cascalog

Let's say I have a set of tuples to be processed by Cascalog, formatted like `[Date, Name, Value]`, e.g.

```
2014-01-01 Pizza        3
2014-01-01 Hamburger    4
2014-01-01 Cheeseburger 2
2014-01-02 Pizza        1
2014-01-02 Hamburger    2
```

Given that I have a list of columns like `[Pizza, Hamburger, Cheeseburger]`, I want to transpose / pivot the data so it looks like this:

```
Date       Pizza Hamburger Cheeseburger
2014-01-01 3     4         2
2014-01-02 1     2         0
```

What's the best way to do this in Cascalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(:use cascalog.api)

(def input
  [["2014-01-01" "Pizza"        3]
   ["2014-01-01" "Hamburger"    4]
   ["2014-01-01" "Cheeseburger" 2]
   ["2014-01-02" "Pizza"        1]
   ["2014-01-02" "Hamburger"    2]])

(defn init-aggregate [k v]
  {k v})

(def combine-aggregate
  (partial merge-with +))

(defparallelagg aggregate
  :init-var #'init-aggregate
  :combine-var #'combine-aggregate) 

(defn select-values [hashmap keyseq]
  (map #(get hashmap %) keyseq))

(def columns
  ["Pizza" "Hamburger" "Cheeseburger"])

(defn transpose [data]
  (<- [?date !pizza !hamburger !cheeseburger]
      ((<- [?date ?sum]
           (data ?date ?name ?value)
           (aggregate ?name ?value :> ?sum))
         ?date ?sum)
      (select-values ?sum columns :> !pizza !hamburger !cheeseburger)))

(?- (stdout) (transpose input))
```

Let's have a quick run through the code:

Most of the action happens in the `transpose` function, which contains two queries:

1. The inner query aggregates all `?name ?value` pairs for a given date into a `?sum` map.
2. The outer query uses `select-values` to fetch the values for our columns out of the `?sum` map, and into the final result rows.

Since we know the columns are `Pizza, Hamburger, Cheeseburger` we can simply hardcode them into the query. If you want to know how to make the columns dynamic, read Nathan Marz's blog post on [creating a news feed in Cascalog](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/news-feed-in-38-lines-of-code-using-cascalog.html).

Note that we have to represent the columns as nullable variables (using `!`) since not every column will have a value for any given row. If we wanted to avoid `null` results, we could change `select-values` to use 0 as the default value.

(One caveat is that this won't produce any headers in the final output, so this has to be done as a post-processing step.)